# Is there any better solution than three nested Maps that preserves the same functionality?

Tags: java, data-structures, collections

Here is the situation

```
private Map<String, Map<String, Map<String, String>>> properties;
```

And I want to have access to all levels - get `Map<String, Map<String, String>>`, `Map<String, String>` or simply just `String` from the inner map.

Can this be done in a better way to avoid this nested structure? Creating a wrapper which would hide the implementation and provide simple methods is the obvious solution but it just hides the main problem.

Comment: You said "Creating a wrapper which would hide the implementation and provide simple methods is the obvious solution but it just hides the main problem."...IMHO this is the whole point of creating a class: To hide one specific problem and expose simple methods to handle it.

Comment: I know, but I'm looking for a solution which (in the best case) does not use these nested maps. Maybe different data structure or better approach

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I like the `Key` approach.

```
public class Key {

   private String keyA;
   private String keyB;
   private String keyC;

   public Key(String a, String b, String c) {
      keyA = "".equals(a) ? null : a;
      keyB = "".equals(b) ? null : b;
      keyC = "".equals(c) ? null : c;
   }

   public String getKey(){
      return keyA + keyB + keyC;
   }

   // equals() can be implemented using getKey()
}
```

And then:

```
Map<Key, String> map = new HashMap<Key, String>();
map.put(new Key("a", "",""), "only one key");
map.put(new Key("a", "b", "c"), "all keys");
```

Do notice that you'll only need one map, and can still get an object with only `keyA` since it will have a different key value.

Of course, if you want to store multiple objects with the same index (or recover multiple objects that start with the same key beginning, as in recover `Key("a", "a", "a")` and `Key("a", "a", "b)` when searching for `Key("a", "a", "")` it will not work. But then, you should not be using a `Map` anyway, and should probably get a proper database.

Comment: you mean map.put(..), didn't u?

Comment: Make sure your successive keys cannot mix ! In your example `Key("abc", "", "").getKey()` will be identical to `key("a", "b", "c").getKey()` which is problematic.

Comment: That's what happens when you don't write your code on an IDE (:

Comment: Nice idea, but I don't think it will work with non-string keys

Comment: ARRG: corrected, if `new Key("abc", "", "");` will return `abcnullnull`.
perissf: OP never asked for a non-string solution (:

Comment: For non-string key you can use its string representation. Another option is to use some hash key generated from key.

Comment: But this won't help me if I want to call in the original example `map.get("a")` and pass it like a map, because I can only get `String` from your solution.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider having a look at Google Guavas Collection classes - maybe you can find a suitable implementation that you could use "out-of-the-box" instead of rolling your own?

Answer (score 0):

A clean solution (although initially more cumbersome) is to [normalize](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) your data, and load them into an in-memory `database`. Then, using [JPA](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbpy.html), you can get advantage of all the `OneToMany` relationships and get collections of objects that share one or more keys.